# How to avoid codeigniter cache

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

we developed a site in codeingiter framework. we are facing a issue in codeigniter cache problem. The problem like this

When user is logged in, our header bar info should be Welcome Mr.xxxxx.
If user is logged out, our header info should be Welcome Guest.

Here user after logged out, the header is showing logged out user name.

While am pressing Ctrl+F5. It will appear correctly.

We tried a lot.

also set database query cache false `$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;`

Inside a cache folder(application\cache) there is no cache file except index.html and .htaccess

The output cache also be `$this->output->cache(0);`.

And Also tried this one.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

Any help or pointing in the right direction will be fine. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using CI's output class?

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/output.html#CI_Output::set_header

```
$this->output->set_header('HTTP/1.0 200 OK');
$this->output->set_header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
$this->output->set_header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', $last_update).' GMT');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
$this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
```