# How to solve cache problem in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, caching

How to solve cache problem in codeigniter.

Changes made in front end reflect in database but in front end changes not reflect, after refresh 10 times then changes visible.

How to re solve this problem, unable to understand please guide me if possible

[Screenshot attachment please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AepY2.jpg)

Comment: Hello @GaNesh. You should give more information to help people understand your problem and help you. You'll find directions here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I do update information in student form, but changes not reflect in student page, but at the same time I look on database changes made there which I have edit....

Comment: not sure i'm understanding the root of your problem. You're caching, but somehow feel that if the cache is acting the way it's supposed to there's a problem?

Comment: How to disable web page caching

Comment: Possible duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775382/codeigniter-disable-cache

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter Disable Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775382/codeigniter-disable-cache)

Comment: if you use 2 different browsers, e.g. FF for admin backend and Chrome for the student page, do you still see the problem?

Comment: what cache are you referring to? the CI database cache? the browser cache? there are many...

Comment: Ok let me clear you question with screenshot scenario

Comment: i have attached above a screenshot please click there to understand problem

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following link  it may help you.
[Avoid codeigniter cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476165/how-to-avoid-codeigniter-cache)

Comment: Problem is still there brother @yogesh

Comment: How to avoid browser cache using Codeigniter

Comment: not solved yet? omg...